# Selenium ChromeDriver Keep and Discard issue while downloading

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can't bypass '**This type of file can harm your computer**'.

Use Java and *Chrome Driver 97+*.

Tried:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\Fedor\\Downloads");
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
prefs.put("download.extensions_to_open", "text/x-python");
    
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But no luck...
[image]

For those who think it's a duplicate, the following links are ***useless*** with the current driver version:

- [How to hide the warning "This type of file can harm your computer" while downloading .xml file using Chrome Chromedriver 79 with Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840198/how-to-hide-the-warning-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-while-downloa)
- [How to disable 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up)
- [Unable to download file using ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319393/unable-to-download-file-using-chromedriver)
- [ChromeOption '--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection' doesn't disables the download warning in Chrome version 67.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405048/chromeoption-safebrowsing-disable-download-protection-doesnt-disables-the-d)
- [How to disable 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130774/how-to-disable-this-type-of-file-can-harm-your-computer-pop-up)
- [XML file download blocked in selenium chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114736/xml-file-download-blocked-in-selenium-chromedriver)
- [Download .xml file with selenium chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762357/download-xml-file-with-selenium-chrome-driver)
- [How to use chrome webdriver in selenium to download files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937319/how-to-use-chrome-webdriver-in-selenium-to-download-files-in-python)

Comment: Any updated on this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the argument:

```
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
```

The following arguments:

```
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
```

should do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have a feeling that --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection and --safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist have been deprecated for quite a while.